# Add a class to images in drupal

Tags: theming, media

I have more than thousand images on my site. adding a class to each image manually is very time consuming process is there any way to add the class "adaptive-image" to all images already uploaded automatically.

Comment: How are you displaying these images? How did you upload them - through something like IMCE or image fields?

Comment: You add the class to the template that displays the images. Else target the  images and surrounding html with appropriate CSS selectors and duplicate the adaptive-image CSS.

Comment: @AramBoyajyan Some images are displayed using direct link in html and others using image fields

Answer (score 1):

Few ways to do this:

1. JavaScript. Not the best one, but fastest:

   ```
   $('img').addClass('adaptive-image');
   ```
2. For styling field images, see the response by Manoj Bisht.
3. For styling images added through WYSIWYG you will have to write a custom text filter and add classes. Depending on the WYSIWYG editor you use, you might be able to create a plugin / set configuration so that all images inserted automatically get certain CSS class.
4. Ultimately, you can just adjust the CSS of `.adaptive-image`, or clone the styles and apply them for all `img` tags.
   Example source:

   ```
   .adaptive-image {
     /* Whatever. */
   }
   ```

   Change to, or add this:

   ```
   img {
     /* Copy styles from .adaptive-image. */
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can write function `theme_preprocess_image`, like the one give below

```
theme_preprocess_image(&$variables) {
  $variables['class']['adaptive-image'][] = "true";
}
```

It will apply adaptive-image class to all images irrespective of style.